# Graph Nodes colour depending on weights

Tags: r, colors, nodes, graph-theory

I have created an undirected graph and I have assigned weigths to each edge.

I would like to modify nodes so that they reflect their degree. I tried to change the size of each node based on its degree, but this produces nodes that are too large.

My idea is to assign a colour to each nodes that is connected with the degree: in example a node with a low degree should appear blue and a node with a high degree should appear red. Nodes in-betwenn should appear from light blue to light red. The color variation is based on the value of the degree, hence there are not thresholds. The degree values are integer: if the value of a node increases by 1, its color should become a bit more red and a bit less blue.

I am using R libraries ipgraph, visNetwork, and tidyverse.

Here is an example:

```
FROM TO WEIGHTS
A    B    15
A    C    10
B    C    20
```

I create a graph from an Excel file similar to the one above: the combination of the first two columns creates edges, while the third column shows the weights of each edge.

In the example above, A has a degree of 25, B of 35, and C of 30.

What I want to do is the following: assigning a colour to A that is blue, then B should be red, and C should be in-between. In this way, the colour should reflect the degree of nodes.

Is there an option to assign color in this way?

Comment: Please post a code and data example. Like this it is really difficult for us to say what to do. You should also say what you mean by *low degree* and *high degree*. Are you deciding based on a threshold value?

Comment: Basically, Rui is asking for a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please edit your question accordingly